# Gas estimation error in really simple code

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, error

When I try to deploy this code without any Value in Remix it works just fine, but as soon as I add any value to this I get the error message:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> execution reverted

I have enough Eth in my test account so that shouldn't be the problem. Thanks for the help.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0 ;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    mapping (address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: just define a payable constructor if you want to be able to deploy with a value.  See this answerr https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957158/5032971

Answer (score 1):

The constructor per default is not payable. If you want to send some value to a contract during deployment, you need to implement a constructor with payable keyword such as this:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0 ;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    mapping (address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    
    constructor() payable {}

    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

However you need to write additional code in the constructor, so that the value sent does not go to limbo.